# Time evolution operator for 2-level system hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hamiltonian, time-evolution, two-level-system

I'm trying to compute the time evolution operator of a system with the following hamiltonian:

$$ H(t) = g(t)[\sigma^+ e^{i \omega t } + \sigma^-e^{-i \omega t }] $$

I tried to use the Magnus expansion, and computed
$$[H(t'), H(t'')].$$

Not like a similar hamiltonian, but with the operators $a$ and $a^\dagger$, this commutator is not equal to a constant, and the magnus expansion cannot be further simplified.

Do you know if it is possible to compute the time evolution operator for such hamiltonian? If it is, could you give me a suggestion on how to proceed?

Comment: Could you define $\sigma^{+/-}$, I'm sure they have something to do with pauli matrices but I'm not exactly sure which ones. Also $g(t)$ is an arbitrary function yes? The magnus expansion will be useful for small times only (is that what you want?) Otherwise trotterization can be used to numerically compute this for a particular $g(t)$. Otherwise, since the pauli matrices form a basis of all hermetian operators, there might be a "guess and check" solution. I can describe more if this sounds useful to you.

Comment: $\sigma^{+,-} = \sigma_x \pm i \sigma_y$, g(t) is an arbitrary function, and the trotterization is what I'm trying to avoid at all costs :'). Could you elaborate on the "guess and check" part? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Typical theorist... the solution is right in front of you but you don't like it aesthetically (joking). I don't really know if this will work - but _any_ 2x2 unitary matrix can be written as $U(t)=\exp[i(a(t)\sigma_x+b(t)\sigma_y+c(t)\sigma_z+d(t)I)]$. There _might_ be a solution where you take a derivative of this (taking the derivative correctly is not completely trivial) and find a way to match it to the Hamiltonian that you want to equal that derivative. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You want to solve the differential equation $\partial_t U = -i HU$ for a generic unitary 2x2 matrix *U*, which you know from your CKM drill resolves to an orthogonal and three trivial diagonal unitary ones,
$$
U(t)= e^{i\phi}\begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\0&e^{i\phi'}\end{pmatrix}  \begin{pmatrix} \cos\theta&\sin\theta\\-\sin\theta &\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\0&e^{i\phi''}\end{pmatrix}.
$$
You differentiate, plug in
$$
H=g \begin{pmatrix} 0&e^{i\omega t}\\e^{-i\omega t}&0\end{pmatrix},
$$
and solve the four differential equations for the components explicitly for the unknowns $\theta,\phi, \phi ', \phi ''$.

You also know $U^\dagger \partial_t U$ is, consistently, antihermitean.